# Php Unique Random Number with exception

Tags: php, sql, random, numbers, unique

I built a random number like this:

```
$numbers = range(0, 14);

$currentWeek = $date->format('W');

shuffle($numbers);

foreach($users as $user) {

    $uniqueRand = (array_pop($numbers)+$currentWeek) % 52 + 1;
}
```

So that gives each user in my db a random number between today to 52 and then start from 1 again if the ranged is not totally filled so to say.

Now I have another column with numbers in my db and I want that the user will not randomly get the same number here.

So like this:

```
Users     |     Number 1      |       Number 2
______________________________________________
Jack      |        10        |         5
```

and not like this:

```
Users     |     Number 1      |       Number 2
______________________________________________
Jack      |        10        |         10
```

something like this is also possible:

```
Users     |     Number 1      |       Number 2
______________________________________________
Jack      |        10        |         5
Daniel    |         3        |         10
```

Comment: can another user get the same number as Jack ?

Comment: Why not use rand(0,14)? that way you will insure that the generated number is always random

Comment: just one user can get the same number as Jack, but not two. I mean like for instance Jack | Number 1 = 10 and Daniel | Number 2 = 10, so in another column.

Comment: if one uses rand there is a possibility that various users get the same number, shuffle is unique